# HTML5 audio in android mobile

Tags: android, html, audio, mobile-application, user-interaction

I'm using html5 to play Audio in Android mobile Application. Is there any way to play the audio without user interaction?.

In iOS there are the following two flags :

```
allowsInlineMediaPlayback =YES
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction =NO
```

That can be used for playing html5 audio without user's interaction. How to achieve this in Android?